# Base64 encode in nodejs and decode in php is different?

Tags: php, node.js, base64

I want to post en file from NodeJs to PHP server.

To do this :

0 - I read a file (a Power Point file)

1 - I encode the file-content in base64

2 - I post the file to the PHP

3 - I decode the file content

4 - I save the file

But when I open the file after the step 4, the file is broken. Anyone say why the decode isn't working ?

nodejs code :

```
fs.readFile(FilePath, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
                if (err) throw err;
                request.post(
                    callback_url,
                    { json: {
                        'document_id': id,
                        'document': Buffer.from(data).toString('base64'),
                        'content_type': mime.getType(resultFilePath + resultFile)
                    } },
                    function (error:any, response:any, body:any) {
                        console.log(body);
                    }
                );
            });
```

PHP code :

```
// set the POST content in $document
$document = base64_decode($document);
file_put_contents($fileName, $document);
```

**Edit :** 
The error was the encoding when I read the file ...
replace

```
fs.readFile(FilePath, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
```

to

```
fs.readFile(FilePath, function(err, data) {
```

Comment: It would be better to write a separate answer to your question instead of editing the answer into the question. Because now it looks like it is an unanswered question (0 answers)

Comment: I want to do this, but I cant post answer to my question.

Comment: Why you can't? Everyone can write answers, and it's even [encouraged to answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was the encoding when I read the file ...
replace

```
fs.readFile(FilePath, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
```

to

```
fs.readFile(FilePath, function(err, data) {
```

Thanks all